# Styled Component theme in TypeScript as published NPM package

Tags: typescript, npm, styled-components

I am creating a NPM package that includes a styled components theme, to be used in any consuming app to provide colours, units, etc.

I have created a `styled.d.ts` to extend the `DefaultTheme` type, and this makes autocomplete work as expected in the repo my package lives in (with Storybook). All good so far.

However, after publishing the app that has installed my package and imported the theme doesn't have any autocomplete because it has no awareness of the type for the theme it's using.

How do I set up the types in the package to be used? How does an app consuming my package become aware of the theme type and provide autocomplete when creating a new styled component?

Answer (score 0):

Are you exporting the theme type in your `styled.d.ts` like so:

```
import type { themeObject } from './themes/my-theme';

type AppTheme = typeof themeObject;

declare module '@emotion/react' {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
  export interface Theme extends AppTheme {}
}
```

I think it may vary dependant on which npm package you're using for creating style components? I am using `emotion` which has a helper method `styled` which I use to create my components like so:

```
import { css, Theme } from '@emotion/react';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';

export const StyledDiv = styled.div<{
  variant,
  theme,
}: {
  variant: DivVariants;
  theme: Theme;
}>`
  color: blue
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colours.primary };
  ...
`;
```

Comment: Please provide examples of your code so we can understand better.
I've provided a use case for you to refer to. Hope this gives you an idea of where to go next even if it's not the right solution for you.